# PHP website debug

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

I have a question,
when cannot run this programme, 
it shows

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'username' (T_STRING) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fypp\index.php on line 9

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['bttLogin'])){
        require 'connect.php';
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $result = mysquli_query($con, 'select * from account where username="'.$username.'" and password="'.$password.'")
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: welcome.php");
        }
        else
            echo "account is invalid";
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password"" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="bttLogin" value="Login"></td>
        </tr>
```

thanks for answering :)

Comment: the syntax highlighter of SO already shows it

Comment: how should i correct it :X thanks

Comment: `mysquli_query` there is no `mysquli` library, there's a `mysql`. Do some general debugging first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error is too specific and is not likely to help anyone in the future.

Comment: i will not work, either u change to mysqli or not.... **WHY** because u missed the termination semi colon for this line         **$result = mysquli_query($con, 'select * from account where username="'.$username.'" and password="'.$password.'")**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, paste your code correctly... You are missing `</table>` and `</form>` in the end...

Second of all, you were missing a simple apostrophe and a semi-colon in the line

`$result = mysquli_query($con, 'select * from account where username="'.$username.'" and password="'.$password.'")`

Also, you should use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysqlui_query`... Typo!

Your code should be as follows :

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['bttLogin'])){
    require 'connect.php';
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con, 'select * from account where username="'.$username.'" and password="'.$password.'"');
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: welcome.php");
    }
    else
        echo "account is invalid";
}
?>

<form method="post">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password"" name="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="bttLogin" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: `mysquli_query`. This is why these types of questions are a poor experience for SO. It's likely not to help anyone at all in the future, just a means to get Karma and help no one, including OP.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I fixed that too in my answer... Didn't mention it... Will do...

Comment: @xrina Kindly select it as an answer if it has solved your problem... :|

Comment: um..... idk why it still have many problems , after i replace it , it shows 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\fypp\index.php on line 7

Comment: because u r not using ending semi colon for termination @xrina

Comment: @xrina I edited my answer... It should be working fine now. You need to focus on proper encapsulation of your torrent. In any case, let me know if it still shows any problem...

Comment: $result = mysquli_query($con, 'select * from account where username="'.$username.'" and password="'.$password.'")   add ending semi colon.. @xrina

Answer (score 0):

Change `mysquli_query` into `mysqli_query`, because it not a valid extension, and i think its typo error.

**Modified Query:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM account 
                          WHERE username='" . $username . "' 
                          AND password ='". $password ."'");
```

Also note that, you missed the termination **semi colon (;)** on the same line.

Comment: r u updating your answer????

Comment: i have modified your  answer.

Comment: your code in syntax error,this true concatenation :)

Comment: i didn't change your code..